# Use a sub directory as root through a PHP file

Tags: php

I have a file `index.php` and a directory `app`. I want to load the contents of the `app` directory whenever I access `index.php` from a variable.

For example:

URL: index.php?url=app/main.php

Code of index.php

```
<?php 
     require "system/index.php";
     $url = $_GET["url"];
     load_file($url); 
?>
```

Here I want load `main.php` from `app` directory with `load_file` function which I have not yet created. The main purpose is to load some files [line:2] before running `app/main.php`.

---

Here is how I implemented the `load_file` function

```
<?php
    load_file($url) {
        require $url;
    }
```

---

### The Problem

Requiring actually loads all the content from the file and prints it. That is required as well as not required for some files. Whenever I require some file, its header gets messed up. That means if URL is `index.php?url=app/video.mp4` it will show the text/code of the video rather than playing the video. Same goes for JavaScript and CSS files. They do load the code but the problem is that all the files no matter CSS/JavaScript/ZIP/Image/Video all of them get interpreted as HTML documents. All that I want is to load each file with their respective headers.

---

Thanks for reading, and please do help if you can.

Comment: try to find out extension of the file from url and then apply some if else

Comment: Dangerous code design. You never should load files by url without having a whitelist.

Comment: Extensions do work, but there are a lot of extensions there, to name a few PDF, DOC, DOCx, MP4, MP3, MPEG-2, etc....  I will need a list of extensions supported in browsers. For the rest I can send download headers. Also I might have to update extensions list everytime, there is a new extension out there.

Comment: `<?php 
     require "system/index.php";
     $_GET["url"] = 'app/main.php';
     $extension_data = explode ('.',$_GET["url"]');
     $extension = !empty($extension_data[1]) ?$extension_data[1]:'';
     $load_file_extension = array('html','js','css','php');
     $play_file_extension = array('.mp4','.mp3','.webam');
     if(in_array($ext,$load_file_extension)){
         load_file($_GET["url"]); 
     }else if (in_array($ext,$load_file_extension)){?>
         // some video html tag code with that file url
     <?php }
?>`  just for example sake

Comment: every file type is different and has different display requirements, so yes you'll need to understand the contents of the file (either by its extension or its mime type) and deal with it appropriately. there isn't really a catch-all solution for this I don't think.

Comment: Easy remote code execution #c99

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to do it. If you want a one-liner you can try [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile):

> readfile — Outputs a file
>
> ### Description
>
> `int readfile ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [,
>   resource $context ]] )`
>
> Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.

Make sure though that you do not print anything else from your script.

Please note that you still need to send a proper `Content-Type` header—the function is called [header()](http://php.net/header).

Comment: Yes I need identify Content-Type of the files. That is what is causing me a lot of trouble. And again thanks.

Comment: Well, that's another question, but you can have a look at [Fileinfo functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).

Answer (score 0):

**This Does Not Solve The Problem** rather introduces a new one

---

***Edit 1***

mime_content_type() does not return the correct /or the required MIME Type for header.

---

I figured out a way of solving it. I had to basically detect MIME Type of the file and send it as header. Thanks to Answer and Comments. I searched google and there exists a function mime_content_type() to identify the mime type.

```
<?php 
     function load_file($file){
         if(file_exists($file)) {
             header("Content-Type:" . mime_content_type($file));
             readfile($file); // Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444074
         }else{
             throw new Exception("File you are trying to find does not exist (/anymore).");
         }
     }
```